# Unable to move file in a folder with the correct permissions

Tags: file-management, file-transfer, file-permissions, fstab

I've got a problem with a sata hdd, it is mounted in fstab like this:

```
UUID="089DD5F442991363" /home/lex/media/archive1  ntfs    rw,users,suid,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,exec,utf8     0       0

UUID="11691863606F1FE2" /home/lex/media/archive2  ntfs    rw,users,suid,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=000,exec,utf8     0       0
```

two partitions, I actually verified and archive1 is mounted as "rwxrwxrwx" or 777, so the umask is correct, but when I try to move a file in it from a folder to another (using first graphical programs then I even tried with "mv") it says I haven't got any permissions.
The strange thing is that my user is the owner: lex:lex.

What's happening? Anybody help, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your kernel support writing to ntfs volumes? I know that there is some write support in the linux kernel ntfs driver, but its very limited:

```
To mount an NTFS 1.2/3.x (Windows NT4/2000/XP/2003) volume, use the file
30  system type 'ntfs'.  The driver currently supports read-only mode (with no
31  fault-tolerance, encryption or journalling) and very limited, but safe, write
32  support.
```

There's a chance you may want to look into ntfs-3g which is able to write to ntfs filesystems.

Comment: Hi!I actually solved this issues by installing ntfs-3g, working with ntfs only was a no go.